# Fade in/out en función de vídeo

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

Tengo el siguiente código.

```
<video id="video" preload="auto">
    <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/media/test.mp4" type="">
</video>
```

Y el siguiente código jQuery dentro de su correspondiente `$(document).on('click', '#video', function (e)`.:

```
var video = $(this).get(0);

if (video.paused === false) {

    video.pause();

} else {

    video.play();

}

return false;
```

Lo que necesito y no logro es que cuando el ratón esté fuera del vídeo, este se mantenga con opacidad `0.2`. Cuando se haga click en él, adquiera opacidad `1` y mientras se esté reproduciendo se quede con esta opacidad. Y el el caso de que se ponga en `stop` entonces vuelva a opacidad `0.2`.

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [mcve] para que veamos el problema? Si necesitas un video de prueba puedes usar [éste](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg) o [éste](https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/frontier.mp4)-

Comment: Como complemento a lo que señala @AlvaroMontoro, videos de prueba en los distintos formatos disponibles para video en HTML5, los puedes encontrar [aquí](http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para manipular la opacidad de los elementos del DOM puedes usar **css** y agregarle una clase al **video** cuando este en pause y quitársela cuando este en play seria algo asi

Para gregar la clase te puse 2 ejemplos con **jquery** y con **javascript** puedes elegir cualquiera de los dos y hacen la misma funcionalidad.

Lo bueno de agregar y quitar una clase es que puedes agregarle todos los estilos que necesites y es fácil de depurar y mantener aparte de que si tienes varios **vídeos** y usan la misma funcionalidad a todos se les agregarían los estilos y cambios.

**css**

```
.enPausa {
  opacity:0.2;
}
```

**js**

```
var video = $(this).get(0);

if (video.paused === false) {

video.pause();
$(this).addClass("enPausa")//jquery
video.classList.add("enPausa")//javascript vanilla

} else {

video.play();
$(this).removeClass("enPausa")//jquery
video.classList.remove("enPausa")//javascript vanilla
}

return false;
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '#video', function (e){
    var video = $(this).get(0);

    if (video.paused === false) {
        //$(this).addClass("enPausa")//jquery
        video.classList.add("enPausa")//javascript vanilla
        video.pause();
    } else {
        //$(this).removeClass("enPausa")//jquery
        video.classList.remove("enPausa")//javascript vanilla
        video.play();
    }

    return false;
});
```

```css
.enPausa {
  opacity:0.2;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="video" autoplay>
        <source src="//clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type=video/mp4>
    </video>
```

Espero te ayude saludos.

Answer (score 1):

necesitas primero que todo tener la opacidad por defecto (0.2) en tu **CSS** y luego por medio de **JavaScript** usando la condición que ya tienes podemos manipular dicha opacidad:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#video', function (e){
    var video = $(this).get(0);

    if (video.paused === false) {
        video.style.opacity = 0.2;
        video.pause();
    } else {
        video.style.opacity = 1;
        video.play();
    }

    return false;
});
```

```css
#video{
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<video id="video" preload="auto">
    <source src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/frontier.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

O usando **jQuery**:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#video', function (e){
    var video = $(this).get(0);

    if (video.paused === false) {
        $(this).css('opacity', 0.2);
        video.pause();
    } else {
        $(this).css('opacity', 1);
        video.play();
    }

    return false;
});
```

```css
#video{
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<video id="video" preload="auto">
    <source src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/frontier.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Me ha servido muuuuuuuy bien, ahora se me presento un problema en el que no pense ayer. Sobre el video tengo un texto y me gustaria que este texto desapareciar al hacer play y volviera a aparecer al hacer pause.No quiero ser pesado ni molesto, de verdad. Pero de momento estoy aprendiendo de forma autodidacta y me cuestan muchas cosas.